# centralManager didConnectPeripheral cannot be called Swift BLE

Tags: ios, swift, macos, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I have passed in my CBCentralManager and CBPeripheral from another View controller to my current View controller using Segue.

```
Class Dashboard: UIViewController ,CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate{


@IBOutlet weak var signalgauge: GaugeView!

var blecentralmanager: CBCentralManager!
var bleperipheral: CBPeripheral!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    }
```

These are called blecentralmanager and bleperipheral.

Now I want to do Connection and Discovering Services and Characteristics

So I called:

```
blecentralmanager.connect(self.bleperipheral,options: [CBConnectPeripheralOptionNotifyOnDisconnectionKey: true])
```

This works fine and connects to the device, But I noticed that the Central Manager DidConnect isn't being called.

```
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
     bleperipheral.discoverServices(nil)
}
```

How can I get my blecentralmanager or bleperipheral to be responded by the DidConnect peripheral ???

Is it because the blecentralmanager and the _central: CBCentralManger are two different variables?

Comment: What object is your delegate?

Comment: Object of my delegate? Well I know that blecentralmanager is an Object of  CBCentralManager, so do I have to set this as a delegate of CBCentralManagerDelegate Protocol?

Comment: `centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral)` is a method of `CBCentralManagerDelegate`. So the `blecentralmanager.delegate` has to be set in order for that method to be called.

Comment: @Larme I get it now, thank you very much for the explanation.  I casted blecentralmanager.delegate = self and it works !